# How To Calculate Typical Deviation?

Tags: javascript

I have to calculate the typical deviation of an array of numbers, Something is failing and I do not not what it is.

I know I am near the solution, however I do not know where I am failing. Also, How do I put code correctly in Stack overflow? CRTL+K only displays a line and putting... does not work

```js
function typical_deviation( array1 ) {
  let array1 = Array(Number) ;
  let sum = 0 ;
  
  for( let i=0, n=array1.length ; i < n ; i++ )
  {
    sum += array1[i] ;
  }
  
  let number_of_study = array1.length ;
  let mean = array1.reduce / number_of_study ;
  
  for ( let i = 0 ; i < number_of_study ; i++ )
  {
     let numerator = ( array1[i] - mean ) ** 2 ;
  }

  let solution = Math.sqrt( numerator / number_of_study ) ;

}

array2 = [2,4,5,6,2] ;
console.log( typical_deviation(array2) ) ;
```

Comment: You're writing over the array1 parameter with the local variable array1, defined with let.  I think your intention was to convert the parameter to an array of numbers, but Array(Number) does not do that (or really anything useful).

Answer (score 1):

As noted, the first statement in your function creates a new `array1` variable that *shadows* the passed-in `array1` parameter:

```
function typical_deviation( array1 ) {
  let array1 = Array(Number) ;
  . . .
}
```

Further, your new `array1` is the result of calling the [`Array` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array), and what `Array(Number)` returns is an array of 1 element, which element is the global `Number` object.

This is probably not what you intended.

Second, you compute a solution, but neglect to return it from the function, so the function always returns `undefined`.

Assuming that the "typical deviation" that you are trying to compute is actually the "standard deviation":

[image: standard deviation formula]

we can calculate it thus:

```
function standardDeviation( measurements = []) {

    let sum = 0;
    for ( const m of measurements ) {
        sum += m;
    }

    const n = measurements.length ;
    const mean = sum / n ;

    let sumOfDeltasSquared = 0
    for ( const m of measurements ) {
        const delta = Math.abs( x - mean ) ;
        sumOfDeltasSquared += delta ** 2 ;
    }

    const sd = Math.sqrt( sumOfDeltasSquared / n );
    return sd;

}
```

But that function is trying to do too many things. Better to refactor it and decompose it into simpler functions that do one and only one thing:

```
function standardDeviation( measurements = []) {
    const mean               = computeMean(measurements) ;
    const sumOfDeltaSquareds = computeSumOfDeltaSquareds( measurements, mean ) ;
    const n                  = measurements.length ;
    const sd                 = Math.sqrt( sumOfDeltaSquareds / n ) ;

    return sd ;
}

function computeMean(arr) {
    const n = arr.length ;
    let sum = 0;
    for ( const x of arr ) {
        sum += x;
    }
    
    const mean = sum / n ;
    return mean;
}

function computeSumOfDeltaSquareds( arr , mean ) {
    let sum = 0 ;
    for (const x of arr ) {
        sum += computeDeltaSquared(x, mean);
    }
    return sum;
}

function computeDeltaSquared( x , mean ) {
    return Math.abs( x - mean ) ** 2 ;
}
```

The advantage of decomposing the problem into trivial problems is that it makes testing/debugging much, much simpler. And because the functions have names that describe what they do, it makes your intent much more apparent to somebody looking at and trying to understand the code (which person might be you).

But we're not done. Javascript comes with a lot of built-in tooling that can simplify things even more. And if it doesn't have it, there are useful packages you can use — e.g., [`lodash`](https://lodash.com/) — that can help you.

Using some of Javascripts built-in tooling (e.g., [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), we can reduce the above to something like this:

```
function standardDeviation( measurements = []) {
    const mean               = computeMean(measurements) ;
    const sumOfDeltaSquareds = computeSumOfDeltaSquareds( measurements, mean ) ;
    const n                  = measurements.length ;
    const sd                 = Math.sqrt( sumOfDeltaSquareds / n ) ;

    return sd ;
}

function computeMean( arr ) {
    const sum = arr.reduce( (sum,x) => (sum += x) , 0 ) ;
    const mean = sum / arr.length ;
    return mean;
}

function computeSumOfDeltaSquareds( arr , mean ) {
    const sum = arr.reduce( (s,x) => (s += computeDeltaSquared(x,mean)) );
    return sum;
}

function computeDeltaSquared( x , mean ) {
    return Math.abs( x - mean ) ** 2 ;
}
```

And we can further simplify that, using Javascript's "arrow functions", to:

```
const computeMean = arr => arr.reduce( (sum,x) => (sum += x) , 0 ) / arr.length ;

const computeDeltaSquared = ( x , mean ) => Math.abs( x - mean ) ** 2 ;

const computeSumOfDeltaSquareds = ( arr , mean ) => arr.reduce( (s,x) => (s += computeDeltaSquared(x,mean)) );

function standardDeviation( measurements = []) {
    const mean               = computeMean(measurements) ;
    const sumOfDeltaSquareds = computeSumOfDeltaSquareds( measurements, mean ) ;
    const n                  = measurements.length ;
    const sd                 = Math.sqrt( sumOfDeltaSquareds / n ) ;
    return sd ;
}
```